# math range error when trying to integrate a function using scipy quad and solving using brentq

Tags: python, scipy, quad

I'd like SciPy to solve the following problem for me:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp, sqrt
import scipy.integrate
import scipy.optimize

def F(x, theta, mu, sigma, r):
    #equation 1
    def integrand(u):
        return u**(r/mu - 1) * exp(sqrt(2*mu / sigma**2) * (x-theta)*u - u**2/2)
    return scipy.integrate.quad(integrand, 1e-5, np.inf)[0]

def Prime(f, x, theta, mu, sigma, r, h=1e-5):
    # given f, estimates f'(x) using the difference quotient formula 
    return (f(x+h, theta, mu, sigma, r) - f(x, theta, mu, sigma, r)) / h

def b_star(theta, mu, sigma, r, c):
    #equation 2
    def func(b):
        return F(b, theta, mu, sigma, r) - (b-c)*Prime(F, b, theta, mu, sigma, r)
    
    return scipy.optimize.brentq(func, -2, 3)

b_star(0.573085, 3.213728, 0.5, 0, 0.001)  # 0.7714361802263615
```

This corresponds with the following equations:

[image: equation 1],

[image: equation 2]

in which I solve the last equation for b.

This seems to work most of the time; however, in some circumstances the following error occurs:

```
In: b_star(0.573085,3.213728,0.137655,0,0.001)
Out:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-1aeb31cb3219> in <module>
----> 1 b_star(0.573085,3.213728,0.137655,0,0.001)

<ipython-input-163-14ce7e008b20> in b_star(theta, mu, sigma, r, c)
     38         return F(b, theta, mu, sigma, r) - (b-c)*Prime(F, b, theta, mu, sigma, r)
     39 
---> 40     return so.brentq(func, -2, 3)
     41 
     42 def V(x, theta, mu, sigma, r, c):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.py in brentq(f, a, b, args, xtol, rtol, maxiter, full_output, disp)
    778     if rtol < _rtol:
    779         raise ValueError("rtol too small (%g < %g)" % (rtol, _rtol))
--> 780     r = _zeros._brentq(f, a, b, xtol, rtol, maxiter, args, full_output, disp)
    781     return results_c(full_output, r)
    782 

<ipython-input-163-14ce7e008b20> in func(b)
     36 
     37     def func(b):
---> 38         return F(b, theta, mu, sigma, r) - (b-c)*Prime(F, b, theta, mu, sigma, r)
     39 
     40     return so.brentq(func, -2, 3)

<ipython-input-163-14ce7e008b20> in F(x, theta, mu, sigma, r)
     18     def integrand(u):
     19         return u**(r/mu - 1) * exp(sqrt(2*mu / sigma**2) * (x-theta)*u - u**2/2)
---> 20     return si.quad(integrand, 1e-5, np.inf)[0]
     21 
     22 def G(x, theta, mu, sigma, r):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    339 
    340     if weight is None:
--> 341         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
    342                        points)
    343     else:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    453             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    454         else:
--> 455             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    456     else:
    457         if infbounds != 0:

<ipython-input-163-14ce7e008b20> in integrand(u)
     17     # equation 3.3
     18     def integrand(u):
---> 19         return u**(r/mu - 1) * exp(sqrt(2*mu / sigma**2) * (x-theta)*u - u**2/2)
     20     return si.quad(integrand, 1e-5, np.inf)[0]
     21 

OverflowError: math range error
```

I tried several solutions like using the Decimal package or the gmpy package to allow for bigger floating point numbers, but the output becomes 0.0 in those cases.

I also tried converting the inputs to a `np.float128` datatype, but this didn't solve the problem either.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: If `gmpy` gives a zero value, what makes you sure that that is incorrect? What do you think the value should be?

Comment: because according to the paper i've gotten the equations from the output is supposed to be bigger than the theta used as input.

Comment: I think the only possible cause of a math range error at the line you report is that the argument to `exp()` is too large. The limit is somewhere between 1e2 and 1e3.

Answer (score 0):

As @BoarGules notes, the argument to `exp` is too large and the result overflows.

Running your code verbatim except for the replacement:

```py
# ~scipy.optimize.brentq(func, -2, 3)~ F(3) overflows
scipy.optimize.brentq(func, -2, 2.5)
```

reveals that there is a root near `0.5636522268679528`. This is not bigger than `theta`, but you can check for yourself that it is a root of the provided equation.

If you can't tighten the bracket you provide to `brentq`, you can use `mpmath` to avoid overflow, replacing calls to `scipy.integrate.quad` and `scipy.optimize.brentq` with `mpmath`'s [`quad`](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/integration.html) and [`findroot`](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/optimization.html).

```py
import scipy
import numpy as np
from mpmath import exp, sqrt, log, mp
mp.dps = 30
# not all `mpf` conversions are strictly necessary, but
# sometimes it's better to be safe.
mpf = mp.mpf

def F(x, theta, mu, sigma, r):
    #equation 1
    def integrand(u):
        return u**(r/mu - mp.one) * exp(sqrt(2*mu / sigma**2) * (x-theta)*u - u**2/2)

    return mp.quad(integrand, (mpf(1e-5), mp.inf))

def Prime(f, x, theta, mu, sigma, r, h=1e-5):
    h = mpf(h)
    # given f, estimates f'(x) using the difference quotient formula 
    return (f(x+h, theta, mu, sigma, r) - f(x, theta, mu, sigma, r)) / h

def b_star(theta, mu, sigma, r, c):
    theta, mu, sigma, r, c = mpf(theta), mpf(mu), mpf(sigma), mpf(r), mpf(c)
    #equation 2
    def func(b):
        return F(b, theta, mu, sigma, r) - (b-c)*Prime(F, b, theta, mu, sigma, r)
    
    return mp.findroot(func, x0=[mpf(-2), mpf(3)], solver='bisect')

b_star(0.573085, 3.213728, 0.137655, 0, 0.001)
```

You can also replace your implementation of `Prime` with use of `mpmath`'s `diff` for a more accurate derivative:

```py
def Prime(f, x, theta, mu, sigma, r):
    return mp.diff(lambda x: f(x, theta, mu, sigma, r), x)
```

There are ways of performing this calculation in log-space with SciPy, but the `mpmath` solution is more straightforward.